# Changing all Class values within the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to replace all the text with the "neden" tag inside the element with the function.

However, since ID is not possible, I am trying to do this with Class. This time it is the same in the texts because it is the same class. Each element needs to show data differently and differently. How can I do that?

```js
var checkDiv = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('.neden').length > 0) {
    changeText(this, $(this).attr('data-neden'));
    clearInterval(checkDiv);
  }
}, 100);

function changeText(eleID, textArray) {
  count = 0;
  wordsArray = textArray.split(",");
  setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    if (textArray.length > 0) {
      $(eleID).fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(eleID).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
      });
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='neden' data-neden='text1,text2'>First</div><br>
<div class='neden' data-neden='text3,text4'>Second</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- `this` is the global object (or undefined in strict mode) inside a `setTimeout` callback, it is not the DOM element with the class that you just checked in the `if` condition.
- `setInterval` will not iterate the different DOM elements. You should use `.each` to iterate them. And if you then want to delay the start of the animation, then call `setTimeout` *inside* the `.each()` callback.
- The function `changeText` defines two variables as globals, meaning that only the last assignment will survive. Instead you should declare them as local variables.
- You can better tune the value of `count`, because now it first gets to be 1 before the first animation. So that means the animation does not start with the first text.
- And the animation should probably better start immediately when `changeText` is called, so also perform the animation directly -- not only after a time out.

Maybe this is what you intended?

```js
$(function () {
    // Iterate the items: one timeout per item
    $('.neden').each(function (i) {
        setTimeout(() => { // Arrow function to maintain `this`
            changeText(this, $(this).attr('data-neden'));
        }, 1000 * i); // Maybe variable timeout?
    });
});

function changeText(eleID, textArray) {
    // Don't start timer when nothing to do
    if (textArray.length == 0) return;
    // Define LOCAL variables
    let count = 0;
    let wordsArray = textArray.split(",");
    function rotate() {
        // Increase count during animation
        $(eleID).fadeOut(400, function() {
            $(eleID).text(wordsArray[count++ % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
        });
    }
    setInterval(rotate, 2000);
    rotate(); // Also call it now
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='neden' data-neden='text1,text2'></div><br>
<div class='neden' data-neden='text3,text4'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute selector to get all elements with `[data-neden]` on them. Iterate the found nodes with `.each()`:

```js
$('[data-neden]').each((i, el) => {
  changeText(el, $(el).attr('data-neden'));
});

function changeText(eleID, textArray) {
  var count = 0;
  var wordsArray = textArray.split(",");
  
  setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    if (textArray.length > 0) {
      $(eleID).fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(eleID).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
      });
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-neden="text1,text2">First</div><br>
<div data-neden="text3,text4">Second</div>
```